# Input "tap" Command missing (Android Terminal Emulator)

Tags: android, input, terminal, emulation, tap

The command "tap" is missing in my Android Terminal Emulator Console, but my friend has it. What do I have to do?

I have Android 4.0.3 installed, Root Rights, Busybox installed

http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/6206/20130325115232.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem(although i have Android 2.3.7) and googling only led me here.

After a little research (looking into the `input`-script, which in fact only launches the class `com.android.commands.input.Input`) i found out that the "tap"-event is first available in android 4.1.1.

See: [Input.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/com/android/commands/input/Input.java), if you browse to one version before you will see the difference.

It seems that it could be fairly easy to make that feature available in older versions just by replacing the Input-class, only if i knew an easy way to do this :) (although i do not know if the other APIs used in the generation of the tap event, e.g. `injectPointerEvent`, are available in older versions.)

P.S.: I hope you are a member of the Resistance otherwise I may regret helping you :)

Comment: yes i play for the resistance (L16) and since i just installed a new rom i got the tap-command ;)